# Docker Compose - Postgres/Postgis - Shinyapp

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, postgis, shinyapps

I have created a composed docker image, which is based on the follow components

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:14-3.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=AAAAAAAA
      - POSTGRES_USER=BBBBBBBBBB
      - POSTGRES_PASS=CCCCCCCCCC
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,postgis_raster
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  shiny:
    container_name: shiny
    build: ./webapp4
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
```

Everything builds up well and goes into operation.

But when the shinyapp tries to connect with the database with the following code

```
remote_conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                         dbname = "AAAAAAAA",
                         host="localhost",
                         port="5432",
                         user="BBBBBBBBBB",
                         password="CCCCCCCCCC")
```

I have the following output

```
Warning: Error in : could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

  55: <Anonymous>
  54: stop
  53: connection_create
  52: .local
  51: dbConnect
  49: server
   3: runApp
   2: print.shiny.appobj
   1: <Anonymous>
Error : could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can Someone explain me how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add same network to both containers?
Just define networks and then add network name to both containers and when connecting make sure to use service name as host argument, in your case it would be

host="db", instead of host="localhost"

For an example look at https://github.com/Tornike-Skhulukhia/postgres-to-mongo-importer/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

Comment: As you suggested, i have create the networks and replace the "localhost" with "db" and now all it is working. Thanks

Comment: Great, you can mark question answer as resolved.